# Print Menu block Title and the menu

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

- In `admin/structure/menu` I created a menu
- In `admin/structure/block` I created a 'menu block' with above menu

With below code I am able to render the menu in `page--front.tpl.php`

```
<?php
 $block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', '3');
 print render($block['content']);
?>
```

But how do I render the Menu block Title?

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is right but you are missing the print subject, you only print the content of the block.

if you debug the $block variable you will find 'subject' as key with value or without value based on the block if it has a title or not.

So your code should be like this in order to print the title.

```
 $block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', '3');
 print render($block['subject']);
 print render($block['content']);
```

Comment: The best solution is always the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

This renders it correctly, including all markup.

```
    $block = block_load('menu', 'menu-my-profile');
    $block = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
    $block = _block_get_renderable_array($block);
    print render($block);
```